# Drag and Drop code snippet for flash Canvas

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, code-snippets

I'm working on a code snippet in Flash Canvas HTML5 to allow an icon to be dragged and dropped over a target, then on release the playhead jumps to a frame number.

Here is what I have so far:

```
this.Brush.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_5);

function fl_ClickToDrag_5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     this.Brush.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_5);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
      this.Brush.stopDrag();
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2014/03/flash-pro-jigsaw.html resource to be invaluable with building a drag and drop activity in the new flash canvas environment.

To make your icon jump to a different frame I would add a `gotoAndStop(/*FrameNumber*/)` inside the on press up function of the tutorial (line 29 or 30 I believe).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.slider.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownFun.bind(this));

function mouseDownFun()

{

    console.log("mouseUpFun");
    this.slider.addEventListener("pressmove", mouseMoveFun.bind(this));
    this.slider.addEventListener("pressup", mouseUpFun.bind(this));
}

function mouseMoveFun()

{

    this.slider.x = stage.mouseX - 42;
}

function mouseUpFun()

{

    console.log("mouseUpFun");  
    this.slider.removeEventListener("pressmove", mouseMoveFun.bind(this));
    this.slider.removeEventListener("pressup", mouseUpFun.bind(this));
}
```